# Totalling Array of objects values using reducer without using find

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am reducing the `data` array down to one entry per DishName with Qty, Cooked and NotCooked values added together if the DishNames are the same.

What I have works, however due to needing compatibility with old devices I cannot use `.find()` with "fat arrows". I've tried racking my brain but cannot come up with a solution.

```js
var data = [
  { DishName: '35. Chicken Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 1, NotCooked: 0 },
  { DishName: '36. Lamb Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 1, NotCooked: 0 },
  { DishName: '37. Prawn Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 1, NotCooked: 0 },
  { DishName: '38. King Prawn Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 1, NotCooked: 0 },
  { DishName: '35. Chicken Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 0, NotCooked: 1 },
  { DishName: '36. Lamb Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 0, NotCooked: 1 },
  { DishName: '37. Prawn Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 0, NotCooked: 1 },
  { DishName: 'Chicken Tikka Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 0, NotCooked: 1 },
];

var res = data.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  var existItem = acc.find(item => item.DishName === obj.DishName);

  if (existItem) {
    existItem.Qty += obj.Qty;
    existItem.Cooked += obj.Cooked;
    existItem.NotCooked += obj.NotCooked;
    return acc;
  }
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: First of all your `data` array is not correct and second, you should clearly define what exactly do you want?

Comment: As per [can I use](https://caniuse.com/?search=Array.prototype.find), you can use it mostly in all browser, but not in `IE`.

Comment: I swear the same question was asked yesterday.

Comment: I've reformatted my Q, just that I cannot use fat arrow functions I think find is ok just without fat arrows.

Comment: Ah ha! [Not the same but similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69035109/count-unique-instances-of-object-property-and-tally-based-on-other-properties/69035242#69035242). Maybe the answers there will help.

Comment: It's better performance (and alleviates this problem) to use an object within the reducer instead of an array.

Comment: @user16824066 + at *James* ... For something like the OP's requirements of a reduced list of merged items it is even better to use a collector which maps (lookup) and collects (result) such un/merged items within a single reduce cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `var existItem = acc.find(item => item.DishName === obj.DishName);` can be rewritten without arrow function as

```
var existItem = acc.find(function(item){return item.DishName === obj.DishName;});
```

Or if you want to avoid using `find` as

```
var existItem = acc.filter(function(item){return item.DishName === obj.DishName;})[0];
```

But i would also change `acc.push(obj);` to `acc.push({...obj});` to avoid mutating the original `data` array.

Comment: Great, @Gabriele Petrioli.
But I think mutating the original data **obj** does not happen when `acc.push(obj);` is used.

Comment: @EJJoier The original data is mutated if you simply push the same object. Then both `acc` and `data` hold a reference to the same object. By using `acc.push({...obj})` you make a shallow copy and place that in `acc`. If a future iteration decides to update `existItem` then it mutates this copy.

Comment: @EJJoier indeed the `push` line does not mutate the original data. but the code in the `if` will do that since `obj` points to the original data.

Answer (score 0):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are slightly different than regular functions but are very similar. In your case, you can just use `find` with a regular function.

```js
var data =
      [
         {DishName: '35. Chicken Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 1, NotCooked: 0},
         {DishName: '36. Lamb Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 1, NotCooked: 0},
         {DishName: '37. Prawn Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 1, NotCooked: 0},
         {DishName: '38. King Prawn Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 1, NotCooked: 0},
         {DishName: '35. Chicken Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 0, NotCooked: 1},
         {DishName: '36. Lamb Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 0, NotCooked: 1},
         {DishName: '37. Prawn Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 0, NotCooked: 1},
         {DishName: 'Chicken Tikka Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 0, NotCooked: 1},
      ]


var res = data.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  var existItem = acc.find(function(item){return item.DishName === obj.DishName});

  if (existItem) {
    existItem.Qty += obj.Qty;
    existItem.Cooked += obj.Cooked;
    existItem.NotCooked += obj.NotCooked;
    return acc;
  }
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach free of `find` has the additional advantage of saving for each step of a full `reduce` cycle the unnecessary `find` iteration.

A solution based on an accumulator which does take care of mapping and collecting un/merged dish-items runs just a single `reduce` cycle.

```js
function mergeSameDish(collector, item) {
  var index = collector.index;
  var list = collector.list;

  var merger = index[item.DishName];
  if (merger) {
    // a (to be) merged dish item.
    merger.Qty = merger.Qty + item.Qty;
    merger.Cooked = merger.Cooked + item.Cooked;
    merger.NotCooked = merger.NotCooked + item.NotCooked;

  } else {
    // collect and map a shallow dish item copy
    // in order to not later mutate the original.
    list.push(
      index[item.DishName] = Object.assign({}, item)
    );
  }
  return collector;
}

var data = [
  { DishName: '35. Chicken Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 1, NotCooked: 0 },
  { DishName: '36. Lamb Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 1, NotCooked: 0 },
  { DishName: '37. Prawn Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 1, NotCooked: 0 },
  { DishName: '38. King Prawn Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 1, NotCooked: 0 },
  { DishName: '35. Chicken Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 0, NotCooked: 1 },
  { DishName: '36. Lamb Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 0, NotCooked: 1 },
  { DishName: '37. Prawn Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 0, NotCooked: 1 },
  { DishName: 'Chicken Tikka Vindaloo', Qty: 1, Cooked: 0, NotCooked: 1 },
];

console.log(
  'mutated/reduced items ...',
  data.reduce(mergeSameDish, {
    index: {},
    list: [],
  }).list
);
console.log('unchanged/original items ... ', data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```